# Shoutcast/Icecast now playing

Tags: flash, icecast, shoutcast, internet-radio

I've a website where I have listed 100s of radio stations and want to display current playing track of every station. I've searched a lot but couldn't find any good solution then I'm not developer but small things I can manage. Is there any script or player that can help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you will be using some sort of push notification from the server as to when the metadata changes.  With this data, you can update a static file or table that all your clients read from regularly.  You can also push updates to clients directly if you use something like WebSockets or long-polling JSON

As an alternative, there are services available for returning the metadata as JSON for an arbitrary stream.  I run one called AudioPump.  You can create an account here:  http://audiopump.co/accounts/

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure for of a code for the whole project but for each station you can do

`Loading ...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://servername/file/recenttracks.js"  > `
```

i got this from centova cast  documentation  http://www.centova.com/en/cast/docs